# Signal Enabling Audio Output on Nexys 4

Tags: audio, verilog, fpga

I everyone! :D I'm in the middle of a Univ. project, that is basically making an audio equalizer with a FPGA, and Verilog. We've already made all the registers, the data capturing, the frequency divider and also the PWM, and we are about to take the signal through the filter in-side the Nexys and then to the final audio-output. So, my question is:
Do I have to make some sort of enabling signal to be able to hear something at the output?

[Here is the user manual](https://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/NEXYS4/Nexys4_RM_VB2_Final_5.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the [Nexys 4 schematics](https://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/NEXYS4/Nexys%204_sch.pdf) there are two signals AUD_PWM and AUD_SD from the FPGA (Page 7) to the audio amplifier for the audio jack (page 3, also page 27 of the Ref Man). SD stands for Shut Down according to the data sheet for the [AD8592](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8591_8592_8594.pdf). The SD inputs to the two amplifiers in the AD8592 have to be driven high, with a minimum high voltage of 2.4 volts.

That's an enable.

I don't see the SD pins to the amps in the Reference Manual.

There's a VHDL demo project for [ISE 14.5](https://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/NEXYS4/Nexys4_PDM_RefProj.zip) that shows AUD_PWM named  pdm_data_o, and AUD_SD named pdm_en_o.  I haven't downloaded the Vivado version to see if it contains Verilog.  That should be enough to find them in the UCF.

Oops in the ISE UCF they're called ampPWM and ampSD.

Comment: Yes, I understand what I have to do with the AUD_PWM (actually is the signal coming out from the PWM), but I didn't saw that I had to enable the AUD_SD, so Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I just used the Nexys 4 to output a musical scale a couple of days ago. Just set the enable ( AUD_SD ) to 1 and outputting sound with AUD_PWM works fine. The audio was actually quite loud. I haven't tested this but one guess is that you could pwm the enable signal to change the volume.